# ebgaramond remove Q-"swash" in Xetex

Tags: ebgaramond, swash

I have a problem with EBGaramond. I need Xelatex because of unicode (Ancient Greek etc.) characters, but the swashy "Q" seems a bit much for the publishers.

I got rid of it in the main text by adding

```
{\addfontfeature{RawFeature=-calt}
```

After \begin{document}, but it's an ugly solution for one (no closing bracket), and doesn't work in footnotes. Other attempts have failed for me, such as

```
\usepackage[lf]{ebgaramond}
\defaultfontfeatures{RawFeature={-calt}}
```

All solutions I find are for how to get them, but how can I remove them? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: It's rather better to answer your own question

Comment: Indeed it seems as though `\defaultfontfeatures` only applies to `\set...font` issued after it. So you can't really use `\defaultfontfeatures` to modify the fonts as loaded by the package. If you load the fonts yourself, `\defaultfontfeatures` works.

Comment: Please don't edit your question to say it's not necessary, the point of the website is to build up a pool of knowledge so that future persons that may also have the same problem can stumble upon this and find the answer. please remove the edit to the title and body of the text, and answer the question yourself. Not only is this allowed, but it's highly encouraged to help build up an "encyclopedia" of knowledge.

Comment: Thanks for the advice -- I think I answered my own question in another case and it didn't meet much appreciation. Changed it now!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could add the feature to the default features for the roman family before loading the style:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures+[\rmfamily]{RawFeature={-calt}}
\usepackage[lf]{ebgaramond}
\begin{document}
Quack --
\end{document}
```

[image]

(curiously the feature is by default active only with xelatex but not with lualatex).

Comment: Indeed this one works. I think whatever problem I had after "setmainfont" did not reoccur, but in case it does, this would provide an alternative.

Comment: The class does a bit more detailed font setup, a simple \setmainfont would probably not give an identical output.

Answer (score 1):

[edit: I put this as an edit in the question first, so the first few comments relate to this.]

I just found a possible solution, but I'll need to check it. I didn't have "setmainfont" in the document, because it gave me some issues and the Font was being loaded by usepackage. But adding the setmainfont command seems to have had the desired effect.

```
\defaultfontfeatures{RawFeature={-calt}}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
```

I'll have to see if I encounter new problems with this or if this works for me.